# How to add collection of int values into a List in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, generic-list

I created this arraylist:

```
List<int[]> arrayList_objects = new List<int[]>();
```

Now i want, that in the moment of a button push a 3*1 array  of int is added, that is what i got:

```
arrayList_objects.Add(int[](0,1,2))
```

well now it gives me a syntax error.
Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You need to specify the type of elements in the list. `List<int> arrayList = new List<int>();`. Or if you want to add int arrays: `List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();`

Comment: you need a new, and braces instead of parenthesis: 
new int[] { 0, 1, 2}
the rest of the code looks correct

Comment: `arrayList_objects.AddRange(new[] { 0, 1, 2 })`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a array list like this:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();
```

or like this:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new int[] { 5, 6, 7 }
};
```

And then do whatever You want with this :)